# php-fpm: hundreds of seconds in the log

Tags: php-fpm

I have nginx+php-fpm web server

So I've noticed in php5-fpm.log many strange lines:

```
[03-Sep-2013 09:25:23] NOTICE: [pool www] child 23999 exited with code 0 after 321.832329 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:25:23] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24082 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:25:41] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24032 exited with code 0 after 259.247887 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:25:41] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24083 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:25:47] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24033 exited with code 0 after 255.954602 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:25:47] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24084 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:25:50] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24014 exited with code 0 after 327.620462 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:25:50] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24085 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:25:55] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24034 exited with code 0 after 254.974653 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:25:55] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24086 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:01] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24035 exited with code 0 after 253.388234 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:01] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24087 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:02] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24036 exited with code 0 after 251.374430 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:02] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24088 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:05] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24019 exited with code 0 after 325.601766 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:05] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24089 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:09] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24037 exited with code 0 after 255.871955 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:09] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24090 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:09] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24038 exited with code 0 after 255.884311 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:09] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24091 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:09] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24039 exited with code 0 after 254.826181 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:09] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24092 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:12] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24040 exited with code 0 after 256.232759 seconds from start
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:12] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24093 started
[03-Sep-2013 09:26:14] NOTICE: [pool www] child 24027 exited with code 0 after 321.722533 seconds from start
```

Can anyone tell me, what are these seconds like `after 321.722533 seconds from start` and what does it mean?

*UPD*

My config is:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
pm.max_requests = 100
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Seconds" is a unit of time; 321 of them is [a little over five minutes](https://www.google.com/search?q=321%20seconds%20in%20minutes).

The reason your processes are exiting and respawning is that you have set the `pm.max_requests` option in your php-fpm pool configuration file.

For example, taken from the default configuration:

```
; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For
; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
; Default Value: 0
pm.max_requests = 500
```

We can see in *your* configuration that it is set to `100`, thus php-fpm recycles the process after it has processed 100 requests.

Comment: So, it means only that concrete thread lived `321` seconds and will be respawned. I can not pay attention on it?

Comment: You can ignore these messages; they are harmless and purely informational.

Comment: These log entries can be avoided by raising the `log_level` parameter in `php-fpm.conf` from `notice` (that is the default value perhaps) to `warning`

Answer (score 2):

What does your `max_requests` setting say?  If this is a busy website, it's likely recycling its child processes once it hits that number of requests - unless it says 0, in which case it could be hitting an internal timeout and closing child processes to save memory during quiet times.  I know the FastCGI processor for IIS does this; it's likely the same situation here.

Src: http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Configuration_File

EDIT: Then that's what's happening.  As soon as one child hits 100 requests, it closes.  PHP-FPM will then open a new one when it is needed (which could be immediately).

Comment: `pm.max_requests = 100` in my config. Plase, see update